# ReactJs get data From Props instead of State

Tags: reactjs, properties, state

How i can get my data from props instead from state im new to react and don't really know how to handle it here is my bin : [my app](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KmVdSwxyXJfWsiGUWC7)

any suggestions or examples?

Comment: State is use for one component while props is use to pass the value from one component to another now tell me why you need a state data in props ? or let me know what you want to do in your sample App?

Comment: i would like to recive the data later from props also from another component so i have to rewerite this with an stateless component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changes the code in your App Please check over here [Demo](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KmW4JaxHgjS99eUSKN7)

```
import React from 'react'
import {render} from 'react-dom'
import { CSSTransitionGroup } from 'react-transition-group'



class SendData extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
     this.state = {
      images: [
        'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150',
        'http://via.placeholder.com/350x151'
      ],
      currentImage: 0
    };
    this.fadeImage=this.fadeImage.bind(this);
  }
  fadeImage(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({currentImage: (this.state.currentImage + 1) % this.state.images.length})
  }
  render()
  {

    return(
      <FadeImage images={this.state.images} currentImage={this.state.currentImage} fadeImage={this.fadeImage}/>
     )
  }
}
class FadeImage extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }



  render() {
    return (
            <div className="image">
      <CSSTransitionGroup
        transitionName="example"
        transitionEnterTimeout={300}
        transitionLeaveTimeout={300}
        >
          <section>
            <button className="button" onClick={this.props.fadeImage.bind(this)}>Click!</button>
            <img src={this.props.images[this.props.currentImage]}/></section>
        </CSSTransitionGroup>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }


render(<SendData />, document.querySelector('#app'))
```